# how to select first n words from a string without including html tags in php

Tags: php

i want to get first n words from text stored in my database without cutting words from middle and i don't want to include html tags. Any help ??
eg. if i have

```
<font size="2" face="georgia">   <span style="line-height: normal; text-align: justify; ">    <font color="#006600"> Indian Institute of Technology </font> - Premier Institutes for Engineering in India. </span>   </font>
```

and i want to get

Indian Institute of Technology - Premier...

Comment: That looks like it's including HTML tags to me...

Comment: cyclone sorry for that now i have corrected, now any help ??

Comment: `n words`. Please clearify it.Is single charecter counting as word like article `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$it=<<<HDOC
<font size="2" face="georgia"><span style="line-height: normal; text-align: justify; "><font color="#006600"> Indian Institute of Technology </font> - Premier Institutes for Engineering in India. </span>   </font>

HDOC;
$it = trim(strip_tags($it));
// spit into words using space as delineator
$itsplit = preg_split('/ /',$it);
// get first n  words
$n = 3;
$out="";
for ($x=1; $x<=$n;$x++)
{  
  $out .=  $itsplit[$x]." ";
}
$out = substr($out,0,-1); //strip last space
echo htmlspecialchars($out); // the htmlspecialchars is to show there are no tags
```

Comment: Thanx a lot sdjuan.....one last thing if i want to keep html tags also than how can i do so...eg. wanted output in above case  <font size="2" face="georgia">   <span style="line-height: normal; text-align: justify; ">    <font color="#006600"> Indian Institute of Technology </font> - Premier</span></font>...

Comment: that's a lot more complex to do since you want words that jump across tags, like the closing font tag. The code above is based on your original question  where it is straight-forward to get to the text by stripping off the tags. To do what you additionally ask needs a whole lot more context to be supplied from you. For instance, will the tags around the text always be the same in all cases? If yes then it is relatively easier as you can just put them back around the stripped text but since you are jumping across that closing font tag that makes it difficult to add back the enclosing tags back

Answer (score 0):

You might consider `strip_tags()` to find whats the last word that is not inside html tags.. and then using `strpos()` to find it in string with html and cut it from beginning to that place

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = ''; // You should specify your string here
$words = 5; // You must define how many words you need to cut from the original string here

echo(wordlimit($string));

function wordlimit($string) { 
   $length = 50;
   $ellipsis = "...";
   $words = explode(' ', strip_tags($string)); 
   if (count($words) > $length) 
       return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $length)) . $ellipsis; 
   else 
       return $string; 
}

?>
```